# Nginx inner wordpress

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I followed http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx to setup wordpress on nginx server. I got two wordpress blog and eshop. Atm there are two vhosts it is `www.my-domain.com` and `eshop.my-domain.com`. My task is to:

`move eshop.my-domain.com www.my-domain.com/eshop`

I am using wp-super-cache.

I tried something like this:

```
server {
    server_name www.my-domain.cz;
    root /var/www/my-domain/blog;
    index index.php;


    include global/restrictions.conf;
    include global/wordpress.conf;
    include global/wordpress-wp-super-cache.conf;


    location /eshop {
            root /var/www/my-domain;
            index index.php;

            include global/wordpress.conf;

            try_files $uri $uri/ /eshop/index.php?$args;
    }

}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: what error do you get ?

Answer (score 0):

Its will redirect http://example.org to http://example.com

```
server {
   server_name www.example.org;
   rewrite ^ http://example.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Here is complete guide on

```
http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule
```

Mod Rewrite of Wordpress

```
location / {
index index.php index.html index.htm;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```